# Facing error while installing datree using Helm v3

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am new to Kubernetes and recently I have tried logging in to my datree dashboard.
The problem is, while trying installing datree on my hyper terminal, the installation fails.

So according to [datree](https://hub.datree.io/) i am supposed to type the following in my terminal.

```
helm repo add datree-webhook https://datreeio.github.io/admission-webhook-datree
helm repo update
helm install -n datree datree-webhook datree-webhook/datree-admission-webhook --debug \
--create-namespace \
--set datree.token=<DATREE_TOKEN> \
--set datree.clusterName=$(kubectl config current-context)
```

I have replaced <DATREE_TOKEN> with my token.
Helm v3 is installed.
And this is the error i am getting

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
helm.go:84: [debug] cannot re-use a name that is still in use
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).availableName
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:486
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).RunWithContext
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:200
main.runInstall
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:280
main.newInstallCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:139
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:1044
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:968
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:141
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:1044
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.6.1/command.go:968
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with my error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an installed version of `datree`. Uninstall the old version and try installing again.

```
helm uninstall datree
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just found out that I had to spin up the minikube server in order to have access to the kubernetes cluster. After doing so, it allowed me to enter into my datree dashboard.